# Sometimes getting null value for windows version and processor type

Tags: c++, c, windows, version, processor

For the most part, the function below works but in rare cases returns a null value:

```
DWORD WinVerMinor() {
   OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
   ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
   GetVersionEx(&osvi);
   return osvi.dwMinorVersion;
}
```

Also cpustr below sometimes ends up being null.  For example, from an executable app cpustr stores the correct string while the very same code produces a null result in a dll (sometimes).

```
char cpustr[255]

void proctype()
{
int nBuff[4];
char szMan[13];
char szFeatures[256];
unsigned nProcessorType;

    // Get CPU manufacturer and highest CPUID
    __cpuid(nBuff, 0);
    nHighestFeature = (unsigned)nBuff[0];
    *(int*)&szMan[0] = nBuff[1];
    *(int*)&szMan[4] = nBuff[3];
    *(int*)&szMan[8] = nBuff[2];
    szMan[12] = 0;
    if(strcmp(szMan, "AuthenticAMD") == 0)
        nProcessorType = 0;
    else if(strcmp(szMan, "GenuineIntel") == 0)
        nProcessorType = 1;
    else
        nProcessorType = 2;
    __cpuid(nBuff, 0x80000000);
    nHighestFeatureEx = (unsigned)nBuff[0];
if(nHighestFeatureEx >= 0x80000004)
    {
        char szCPUName[49];
        szCPUName[0] = 0;
        __cpuid((int*)&szCPUName[0], 0x80000002);
        __cpuid((int*)&szCPUName[16], 0x80000003);
        __cpuid((int*)&szCPUName[32], 0x80000004);
        szCPUName[48] = 0;
        for(int i=(int)strlen(szCPUName)-1; i>=0; --i)
        {
            if(szCPUName[i] == ' ')
                szCPUName[i] = '\0';
            else
                break;
        }

        for (int z=0; z < strlen(szCPUName); z++) {
            cpustr[z] = szCPUName[z]; }
    }
return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for the (sometimes) null values?

Comment: FWIW it seems to be deprecated. See [Version Helper Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: *If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call *GetLastError**  -  you don't appear to be checking the return value from GetVersionInfoEx or calling GetLastError, so do that first.  Also, if the version is indeed Windows 10 and you have the application manifest setup, the return value from your `GetMinorVersion` function will return 0, since the version is 10.0.  (Vista was 6.0)